# Prove that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ is connected?

Tags: general-topology

Prove that  $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ is connected ?

My attempt : take $A= (-\infty, 0)$ and $B= (0,\infty)$

$\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}=A\cup B = (-\infty, 0)\cup (0,\infty)$

squaring both side we have

$\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}=(A\cup B)^2 = ((-\infty, 0)\cup (0,\infty))^2=(0,\infty) \cup (0, \infty)$

where$(0,\infty) \cap (0, \infty)\neq \emptyset$ since $(-\infty,0)^2= (0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty)^2=\infty$

Therefore $\mathbb{R^2} \setminus \{0\}$ is connected

Is its correct ?

Comment: $A,B$ appear to be half lines, yes?  It is not true that $\mathbb R^2-(0,0)=A\cup B$.

Comment: For the problem,  I suggest proving that it is path connected.  That's stronger than just "connected".

Comment: It's not true that $(\mathbb R\setminus\{0\})^2=\mathbb R^2-\{(0,0)\}$

Comment: Do you understand that $\mathbb R^2=\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ denotes the set of all pairs $(x,y)$ with $x,y\in\mathbb R$? Because you write "squaring both sides" and then perform a very dubious operation.

Comment: Your assertion that $(A \times B)^2 = A \times B$ is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even better, letting $C$ be a countable set, $\Bbb R^2\setminus C$ is path-connected. One way to see this is as follows:

Let $a=(a_1,a_2),b=(b_1,b_2)\in\Bbb R^2$. Consider $A$ the set of all straight lines passing through $a$, and $B$ the respective set for $b$. Note that we can parametrize the lines of $A$ as $x=a_1$ (the vertical line) and $y-a_2=m(x-a_1), m\in\Bbb R$ (the rest of them). Similarly $B=\{x=b_1,y-b_2=k(x-b_1):k\in\Bbb R\}$.

Now, for each point $c\in C$ there is exactly one line in $A$ passing through $c$ (since a straight line is determined by two points). Since $C$ is countable, but $A$ is not (note we have as many lines in $A$ as real numbers), there is some line in $A$ that never passes through any point of $C$ (so that line lies in $\Bbb R^2\setminus C$). Name that line $r$.

$r$ has a certain slope (it could $\infty$ if it is the vertical line), and there's only one line in $B$ with the same slope (a line is determined by a point and its slope), call it $r'$. Now consider the set $B\setminus\{r'\}$, which is still uncountable, so, as before, there is some line in $B\setminus\{r'\}$ that never passes through any point of $C$ (so that line lies in $\Bbb R^2\setminus C$). Name it $s$.

We have two lines, $r$ and $s$, lying in $\Bbb R^2\setminus C$, one passing through $a$ and the other passing through $b$, and the two of them with different slopes, which implies that $r$ and $s$ intersect each other at some point. This means we have got a path from $a$ to $b$ (or viceversa): we can start at $a$, from there go through $r$ up to its intersection with $s$, and then go through $s$ to end up at $b$.

Technically, we'd need to give a continuous function $\gamma:[0,1]\to \Bbb R^2\setminus C$, such that $\gamma(0)=a$ and $\gamma(1)=b$, but I'll leave that to you; you'll have to define $\gamma$ by parts, using (thus having to name) the point of intersection.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

In this context $X^2$ does not denote the set of all squares formed from elements of $X$, as you seem to be interpreting it.

For a set $X$, the notation $X^2$ denotes the cartesian product
$$
X^2 := X\times X := \{\, (a,b) \,|\, a,b\in X \,\}
$$
consisting of all pairs with both entries elements of $X$.

Hence $\mathbb R^2$ is the [two-dimensional Euclidean space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-dimensional_space) (the plane) and $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$ is the plane with the origin removed. Here $0$ is just a short notation for $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Just  show that $\mathbf R^2$ is path-connected, noting this it is obvious for two points which are at the same distance from the origin.